# floating action button overlaping bottom navigation in android

Tags: android, xml

I'm making an app where my floating action button is overlaping my bottom navigation bar i'm trying to put fab above navigation bar but it is not working fab is overlaping bottom navigation bar below is xml file
I searched on SO but didnt get any proper solution please any help would be appreciated

i have made a separate xml for bottom naigation layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/nav_color"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_fore_color"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is xml for activity main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

<com.ct.listrr.widget.BounceScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.ct.listrr.MainActivity"

    >


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="340dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/club_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <com.ct.listrr.widget.CustomTextViewMedium
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:text="Clubs"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/White"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/clubrecycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lounge_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <com.ct.listrr.widget.CustomTextViewMedium
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:text="Lounge"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/White"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/loungerecycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cafe_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <com.ct.listrr.widget.CustomTextViewMedium
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:text="Cafe"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/White"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/caferecycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rooftop_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <com.ct.listrr.widget.CustomTextViewMedium
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:text="RoofTop"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/White"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_recycle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rooftoprecycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</com.ct.listrr.widget.BounceScrollView>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_my_icon"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:rippleColor="@color/colorAccent"/>
    <include layout="@layout/bottom_nav_bar"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_bar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: your question is not clear..please clearly mention what do you need to archive..as per android design guidelines FAB should be above every other view you are creating

Comment: yes fab should be above every view but my fab is not showing above my bottom navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

Use Layout above parameter inside FloatingActionButton

```
android:layout_above="@id/bottom_nav_bar"
```

Here is your complete xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <com.ct.listrr.widget.BounceScrollView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.ct.listrr.MainActivity"

        >


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="330dp"
            android:layout_height="340dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/club_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <com.ct.listrr.widget.CustomTextViewMedium
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:text="Clubs"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:textColor="@color/White"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/clubrecycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lounge_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <com.ct.listrr.widget.CustomTextViewMedium
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:text="Lounge"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:textColor="@color/White"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/loungerecycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cafe_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <com.ct.listrr.widget.CustomTextViewMedium
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:text="Cafe"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:textColor="@color/White"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/caferecycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/rooftop_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <com.ct.listrr.widget.CustomTextViewMedium
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:text="RoofTop"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:textColor="@color/White"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_recycle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rooftoprecycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </com.ct.listrr.widget.BounceScrollView>


        <include layout="@layout/bottom_nav_bar"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_bar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_my_icon"
            android:layout_above="@id/bottom_nav_bar"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:rippleColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: replace above code with your activity main.xml and then check

Comment: you need to remove android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" from FloatingActionButton and need to add android:layout_above="@id/bottom_nav_bar"

Comment: Hii i want the fab to be at bottom but above bottom navigation if i remove align parent bottom then how can i arrange it at bottom

Comment: we are giving relation so you already gave align parent bottom true to bottom navigation so your floating action button will appear at bottom

Comment: when i'm trying to add layout_above it is showing unknown attribute in fab

Comment: try to replace your main_activity.xml with I given xml to you. I checked that and it will give you similar output as you expected

Comment: see this I am getting this output : https://ibb.co/iz3e97, In this you can see black bottom navigation bar and above navigation it is having floating action button

Comment: i dont know what's wrong but still it is not working

Comment: you have seen image I shared with you? You need result as per that right?

Comment: can you share Image which you are getting now with above code I sent you?

Comment: See @Nik i have shared a screenshot of image

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:text="@string/title_home"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation">

</android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:elevation="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't actually find any fix to this.
What I've made, is to set the `floating action button marginBottom` to `?attr/actionBarSize`.
It won't look that great, but at least it stops overlapping the screen.

EDIT2: i believe ive found the solution. Try setting the parent view marginBottom to ?attr/actionBarSize.